# Cloud Bigtable Failure due to NPN/ALPN extensions not installed

Tags: java, google-cloud-bigtable

Trying to interact with Google Cloud Bigtable via Java lib and after successfully creating connection object, send "list" command and I am getting the following error for `command.run()` method:

```
command.run(connection, argsList.subList(1, argsList.size()));
```

specifically:

```
Jul 06, 2015 1:12:15 PM io.grpc.transport.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$AbstractBufferingHandler fail
SEVERE: Transport failed during protocol negotiation
io.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineException: io.grpc.transport.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$1$1.handlerAdded() has thrown an exception; removed.
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:600)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:582)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.addFirst0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:124)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.addFirst(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:108)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.addFirst(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:291)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.addFirst(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:246)
at io.grpc.transport.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$AbstractBufferingHandler.channelRegistered(ProtocolNegotiators.java:233)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelRegisteredNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:32)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRegistered(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:50)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRegistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:114)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRegistered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:833)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:487)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$100(AbstractChannel.java:401)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:461)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:322)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:356)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:703)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: NPN/ALPN extensions not installed
```

Just following;https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples-simple-cli

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I have java version "1.7.0_60" installed so I've updated pom entry as; 
<alpn.version>7.1.0.v20141016</alpn.version> however it does not help anything...

Comment: Your start line should include the -Xalpn-boot-xxxxxxx.jar  If that is wrong, things will fail.

Comment: I am debugging the code thru eclipse. Since I have that alpn.version entry in the pom, I should be good to go right? Please clarify!

Comment: Nope - your eclipse run tab should have an -Xbootclasspath/p:$(pwd)/lib/bigtable/alpn-boot-${ALPN_VERSION}.jar line of some kind.  Otherwise things will never work.

Comment: Interesting. May we know why we need to have that entry at run time variables? though we have pom with the following entry and I see the jar downloaded to .m2          <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty.alpn</groupId>
      <artifactId>alpn-boot</artifactId>
      <version>7.1.0.v20141016</version>
     </dependency>

Comment: It downloads it, but it doesn't load it at the front of all classes.

Comment: Look at http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.8.v20150217/alpn-chapter.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is necessary to modify your eclipse java run to load the alpn-boot jar in front of all other classes / jars.  Using the line:

> `-Xbootclasspath/p:$(pwd)/lib/bigtable/alpn-boot-${ALPN_VERSION}.jar`

For more information, see [ALPN](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.8.v20150217/alpn-chapter.html).

For Unit Testing in Maven, you can look at our [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/blob/master/bigtable-hbase-integration-tests/pom.xml#L76)

**UPDATE** You can now work w/o alpn-boot by using the [Netty TCNative jar w/ BoringSSL](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-tcnative-boringssl-static/1.1.33.Fork13) we have two examples with that currently, the [Managed-VM-Sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/java/managed-vm-gae) and the [Quickstart](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/quickstart).  See the `pom.xml` for the details, the MVM sample shows how to setup your pom to compile locally and deploy.  The Quickstart pom shows a compile and run on the same machine form.  We hope to have all the Java samples using this soon.

Comment: Les, is there anyway that we can include this bootclasspath entry somewhere so that individual UT debug configuration wouldn't need to include that?

Comment: It's so dependant on your environment, are we talking about Eclipse? IntelliJ? or Netbeans?

Comment: Around the same issue, I see that "mvn install" also fails with the same issue so it is not Eclipse UT debugging config